# Keyboard not working after update 18.04 --> 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, laptop

My laptop keyboard stopped working after an update to Ubuntu 20.04. The solutions mentioned in other threads, such as (re)installing `xserver-xorg-input-all`, changing stuff in the GRUB menu, changing the keyboard layout/language or enabling/disabling stuff in the "Universal Access" menu (such as AccessX) didn't worked at all. My external keyboard works fine, but I need to get the default keyboard working again.

[image: neofetch screenshot]

[image: "about" settings screenshot]

Comment: For me, a similar problem was not a software problem at all, but EC controller needed a reset, see here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1415055/532917

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue happened to me. I installed Kubuntu 20.04 on my wife's notebook HP Pavilion x360. The installation was successful but after the update, the keyboard and the touchpad didn't work. Then I've tried with a lot of others distributions (KDE Neon, Manjaro KDE, Mint MATE, Zorin Core...) and the same occurred.

I solved the problem at GRUB choosing the kernel 5.3.0-40 or 5.3.0-42 instead of 5.3.0-45 or 5.3.0-47 but I have to choose it every boot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Ubuntu thinks your PC is a tablet and diables the keyboard.
The fix below works if the following command gives you any number that is **not** `31` or `32`.

```bsh
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
```

**How to fix this:** (from https://askubuntu.com/a/1282269/558457)

> There is a bug in recent kernels that disables some laptop keyboards. Mainly Acer and HP so far.  Can usually go to recovery and boot from kernel 5.4.0-42 or use an external keyboard.
>
> Blacklisting the `intel_vbtn` kernel module is a workaround for this, as seen in [Why my laptop's keyboard screwed up since kernel 5.4.0-47 till 5.8.0-20](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/)
>
> To implement this, you can either create a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d` with the suffix `.conf` or use the main `blacklist.conf` file. The former may be preferable, since you can then just delete the file when it is no longer required (i.e. when the bug is fixed):
>
> `sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf`
>
> Add a line to the file, optionally with a comment explaining why you are doing this
>
> ```bsh
> # bug in module breaks keyboard, so don't load it
> blacklist intel_vbtn
> ```
>
> Save the file, exit and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Worked well for me:

```bsh
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
reboot
```

This changes **libinput** to **evdev** and **synaptics**.

Hope this will help someone!

[See what changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfGGd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 identical Ubuntu 21.x systems. I tried everything above on one of them, undoing each strategy before trying the next.  I came across the suggestion to do a COLD reboot on another site. This worked on both systems.  So before you go changing config files etc., see if this will work for you - it's certainly the easiest solution.