# Laptop keyboard stops working after apt update

Tags: apt, keyboard, xorg, laptop, xserver

I am fairly new to the world of Linux. This morning I installed Ubuntu 21.10 on my Fujitsu Lifebook U749. It's working good but I have the problem that the laptop keyboard stops working after running `sudo apt update` followed by a reboot. A USB keyboard I attached works. I get the laptop keyboard working again by running `sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-all` followed by `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` in the terminal. The keyboard will then work again after a reboot. If I then run a `sudo apt update` again, and reboot the system, the keyboard is 'broken' again.

How can I resolve this issue so doing `sudo apt update` doesn't break my keyboard?

Comment: `sudo apt update` by itself does absolutely nothing, as in no change whatsoever. As such it CANNOT be the cause.

Comment: Maybe one of the solutions on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269284/keyboard-not-working-after-update-18-04-20-04?rq=1) can help.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Precies! Ik vond het apart dat het toetsenbord werkte maar nadat ik Brave installeerde via de terminal, een reboot deed het opnieuw stuk was.

Comment: @randomperson Thanks, will check that!

Comment: The problem seems to happen randomly I've noticed. Sometimes it works after a reboot, sometimes it doesn't...

Comment: I'm having a similar problem since today, on ubuntu 18. For me, closing the lid of the laptop and opening it again (then I have to login again) does the trick. Just logging out without closing the lid does not seem to help though.

Comment: At the moment it seems like [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340274/606260) fixed it for me